# Delete users from Joomla V2.5

Tags: mysql

I am having an outside contractor work on my joomla site, and want to protect the users and passwords. I cannot use the solution in this thread since I have too many users - [Bulk user delete on joomla 2.5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/bulk-user-delete-on-joomla-2-5)

I have "cloned" the site to a new url, and then used MySQL Workbench to delete all of the users and the user groups map file.

DELETE FROM hhd_users where id>32;
DELETE FROM hhd_user_usergroup_map where user_id >32;

However, I now receive a 500 error after trying to login.  I cannot use the admin to delete users, even if I can show 1,000 on a screen at once because I have ~20,000 users in the DB.

Is there an easier way to delete the usernames and passwords? Is there another table I should have deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the only Super User (main administrator), you may find your own record in `hhd_users` and `hhd_user_usergroups_map` tables, make a record of it, or copy relevant data to some text file, and then EMPTY both tables.
Then create new records in both tables for yourself again, this time as only user in them.

Comment: I  did something similar, and it worked until I changed the password.  Now I have a 500 error. Is the password stored in a different table? Or could this be a problem with the asset map or something?

Comment: @HamletHub You could try to create a new Admin. Follow this documentation https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Comment: Adding new Admin with password as per docs.joomla.org worked, thank you very much!